# How can I move dlls/project files to a new folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm using SFML with Visual Studio and want to move the dlls and vcproj files somewhere else besides the root. How could I do this? Right now, I have the project folder with all the dlls in the same path as the vcproj and solution files, but it looks really messy. I'd like to tranfer the vcproj files and related files to a VS folder, and transfer the dlls to a vendor folder.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the output directory of the dll in dll project's properties or just muanually move them and set the dll dependencies. It is not recommended  to edit the vcproj file manually. Reference: [vcxproj and .props file structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-170). Why not create the rogue like project in VS file, which is much easier.